# Problem with async_read when packet length is more or less

Tags: c++, asynchronous, network-programming, boost-asio

I've checked a Boost example and tested a lot, but I think `async_read` doesn't get invoked properly when the packet (received data) is less or more than its expected buffer.

There is [a server](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/ssl/server.cpp) and [a client](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/ssl/client.cpp) SSL example on boost.org. In the client example after handshake is done, `send_request()` gets invoked and then `send_request()` with the exact length of the sent text. What happens if `send_request()` didn't know about length of packet?

There are three situations for this (by length of buffer I mean `length` argument in `boost::asio::buffer(reply_, length)`):

#### Packet length is equal to buffer length

No problem, we got the packet.

#### Packet length longer than the buffer length

We get as much as the packet length, and what remains is received in another turn. The problem is we can't get the rest of the packet by putting another `send_request()` in the lambda body. The remains we will get when another `send_request()` is called (and so on):

```
void receive_response(std::size_t length)
{
    boost::asio::async_read(
        socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(reply_, length),
        [this](const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t length)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                std::cout << "Reply: ";
                std::cout.write(reply_, length);
                std::cout << "\n";
                receive_response(length);            <---- This one
            }
            ...
        }
    );
}
```

#### Packet length is less than the buffer length

I've changed the handshake lambda a bit so that I can simulate this one, like the following piece of code. I've also changed the `receive_response()` and `send_request()` methods so that they don't invoke each other. I've expected lambda of `async_read` (in `receive_response()`) get invoked after two `async_write`s (in `send_request()`) fill the buffer, but it didn't.

```
void handshake()
{
    socket_.async_handshake(
        boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
        [this](const boost::system::error_code& error)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                receive_response(10);        // Trigger async_read for length 10
                send_request();                // Send a string of length 5
                send_request();                // Send a string of length 5
            }
            ...
        }
    );
}
```

One may suggest using `async_read_some()`. I've tested that too. Fortunately it get invoked by first `send_request()`, but the second `send_request()` didn't invoke the `async_read_some()` lambda (I've put another `receive_response()` in the body of lambda to make a loop).

```
void receive_response(std::size_t length)
{
    socket_.async_read_some(
        boost::asio::buffer(reply_, length),
        [this](const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t length)
        {
            ...
            receive_response(length);
            ...
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: This question appears to mix `send_request()` and `receive_response`. Obviously the sender knows how much data is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

SSL is not that relevant. It's a stream, like TCP.

That means the receiver can't know how much data will be sent. The sender can always send another byte. Hence, after `boost::asio::async_read` you should process what you can, and keep what you can't.

Obviously, you can't keep the data from the first call in the same location where the second call of `boost::asio::async_read` will store the next results. That would just overwrite the results you wanted to keep. There are many solutions: use a second buffer, or remember how many bytes you have already in your `_reply` and create a `boost::asio::buffer(_reply+offset, length-offset)` buffer beyond that.